# Why Can't I Delete File From Path?

Tags: java, android

The code below is not deleting the file using API 33, but it's saying the file does exist though. I am not sure why the file is not deleting from external storage path?

Here is the code that I have...

```
File file = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Pictures/IMG_20230211_060830.jpg");

if (file.exists()) {
    file.delete();
}
```

The file did not delete from file path, but it seems to work fine with API 31.

Comment: You do not have write access to arbitrary content on Android 11+, which includes deleting arbitrary content.

Comment: which `targetSdkVersion` are you using? indeed, are you using `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in the manifest?

Comment: if (file.exists() && file.canWrite()) {
    if ( !file.delete( )) return;
}

Comment: Thanks everyone! Unfortunately, none of the responses are working for me. I think CommonsWare is right. Deleting files can not be done this way anymore.